# I am trying to return value that I set but it's returning the wrong value

Tags: java

I am not sure why it doesn't return the correct value in getPriceDollar. On the first test, it was correct, but on the second, it wasn't.

It seems that it is not working as expected, but I see that there is a problem with  the memory. In the moment I returned it, it already may have be something else. So it is undefined behaviour, am I correct?
How to avoid that?

```
public class FoodTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Food object = new Food();

        object.setName("Kaisen Don");
        System.out.print( object.getName() + ":");

        object.setPrice(480);

        System.out.print(object.getPrice() + " Bath");

        System.out.print( +object.getPriceDollar() + " $ ");
        object.setCalories(350.0);

        System.out.println( +object.getCalories() + " kCal ");



        object.setName("Tokyo Sundae");
        System.out.print( object.getName() + ":");

        object.setPrice(180);

        System.out.print(object.getPrice() + " Bath");

        System.out.print( +object.getPriceDollar() + " $ ");
        object.setCalories(500.5);

        System.out.print( +object.getCalories() + " kCal ");


    }

}

public class Food {
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private double calories;

    public String getName() {           
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name1) {
        name=name1;
    }

    public double getCalories() {           
        return calories;            
    }

    public void setCalories(double calories1){
        calories=calories1;
    }

    public int getPrice() {         
        return price;
    }

    public double getPriceDollar() {            
        return  price / 32;
    }


    public void setPrice(int price1) {          
        price=price1;
    }

}


expected 
Kaisen Don:480 Baht (15.0$) 350.0 kcal
Tokyo Sunday:180 Baht (5.625$) 500.5 kcal
actual results
Kaisen Don:480 Bath15.0 $ 350.0 kCal 
Tokyo Sundae:180 Bath5.0 $ 500.5 kCal
```

Comment: you miss parentheses around price value here `System.out.print( +object.getPriceDollar() + " $ ");`

Comment: "problem with the memory"?  Huh?  Use your debugger and narrow down the specific operation which is producing an unexpected result.  As you step through the code in your debugger, observe the values of your variables.  Which specific line of code is producing an unexpected result?  What were the values of the variables being used on that line?  What was the observed result?  What was the expected result?  Why?

Answer (score 1):

Division in Java is a tricky thing. When dividing an integer by another integer, the result is truncated to an integer, exactly as you are experiencing it. And alas, it doesn't help that you declare the result should be a double, the compiler still does an integer division, and only then returns the integer result converted to a double.

Change the `getPriceDollar()` method to read:

```
public double getPriceDollar() {            
    return  price / 32.0;
}
```

Then it's an integer-by-double division that results in a `double`, and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return integer at place of price. That's why you are getting that result. 
This code will give you the right result-

```
public class FoodTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Food object = new Food();

    object.setName("Kaisen Don");
    System.out.print( object.getName() + ":");

    object.setPrice(480);

    System.out.print(object.getPrice() + " Bath");

    System.out.print( +object.getPriceDollar() + " $ ");
    object.setCalories(350.0);

    System.out.println( +object.getCalories() + " kCal ");



    object.setName("Tokyo Sundae");
    System.out.print( object.getName() + ":");

    object.setPrice(180);

    System.out.print(object.getPrice() + " Bath");

    System.out.print( +object.getPriceDollar() + " $ ");
    object.setCalories(500.5);

    System.out.print( +object.getCalories() + " kCal ");


}

}
class Food {
private String name;
private double price;
private double calories;

public String getName() {           
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name1) {
    name=name1;
}

public double getCalories() {           
    return calories;            
}

public void setCalories(double calories1){
    calories=calories1;
}

public double getPrice() {         
    return price;
}

public double getPriceDollar() {            
    return  price / 32;
}


public void setPrice(double price1) {          
    price=price1;
}

}
```